# Testing with GraphAware Timetree

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, graphaware

I've been starting to use GraphAware timetree for neo4j, and so far its working out pretty well. Now I'm trying to work out how I can unit / integration test my code that uses neo4j timetree.

I've put together some code as below... but still I'm getting the message:

```
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher "Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound"; Code: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound; Description: There is no procedure with the name `ga.timetree.events.attach` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

Am I sort of on the right track?

```
package myproject.core;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.DynamicLabel;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.neo4j.ogm.testutil.MultiDriverTestClass;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jOperations;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.graphaware.common.policy.NodeInclusionPolicy;
import com.graphaware.module.timetree.module.TimeTreeConfiguration;
import com.graphaware.module.timetree.module.TimeTreeModule;
import com.graphaware.runtime.GraphAwareRuntime;
import com.graphaware.runtime.GraphAwareRuntimeFactory;

import myproject.core.context.TestPersistenceContext;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestPersistenceContext.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class AbstractTest extends MultiDriverTestClass {

    @Inject
    private Neo4jOperations neo4jOperations;

    public AbstractTest() {
        new SessionFactory("myproject.model.pojos").openSession();

        TimeTreeConfiguration timeTreeConfiguration = TimeTreeConfiguration.defaultConfiguration();
        TimeTreeModule timeTreeModule = new TimeTreeModule("TT.1", timeTreeConfiguration, super.getGraphDatabaseService());

        GraphAwareRuntime runtime = GraphAwareRuntimeFactory.createRuntime(super.getGraphDatabaseService());
        runtime.registerModule(timeTreeModule);
        runtime.start();
    }

    @After
    public void clearDatabase() {
        neo4jOperations.query("match (n) detach delete n;", new HashMap<>());
        neo4jOperations.clear();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change your `AbstractTest()` constructor to read as follows:

```
public AbstractTest() {
    new SessionFactory("myproject.model.pojos").openSession();

    TimeTreeConfiguration timeTreeConfiguration = TimeTreeConfiguration.defaultConfiguration();
    TimeTreeModule timeTreeModule = new TimeTreeModule("TT.1", timeTreeConfiguration, super.getGraphDatabaseService());

    TimeTreeProcedures.register(super.getGraphDatabaseService());

    GraphAwareRuntime runtime = GraphAwareRuntimeFactory.createRuntime(super.getGraphDatabaseService());
    runtime.registerModule(timeTreeModule);
    runtime.start();
}
```

Note the added line: `TimeTreeProcedures.register(super.getGraphDatabaseService());`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!