# Graphaware TimeTree procedures in unit test using embedded db

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, graphaware

UPDATE: I found some similar test in neo4j timetree source but using  GraphAwareIntegrationTest, which extends ServerIntegrationTest. So I tried creating a GraphDatabaseService  Bean for my test with the following, but still no luck. I get "There is no procedure with the name `ga.timetree.events.attach` registered for this database instance."  Is this not possible?

```
@Bean
  public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
    GraphDatabaseService gds = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabaseBuilder().newGraphDatabase();
    Procedures procedures = (Procedures)((GraphDatabaseFacade) gds).getDependencyResolver().resolveDependency(Procedures.class);
    try {
        ClassPathProcedureUtils.registerAllProceduresAndFunctions(procedures);
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("error", ex);
    }
    return gds;
}
```

=====================

Similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447328/testing-with-graphaware-timetree) but I'm using Spring Boot 2, SDN5 with neo4j 3.2.5, graphaware and time tree. I have automatic event attachment setup, and i see events getting saved to the timetree, but I can't query using the procedure call using cypher. I get the error:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher; Code: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound; Description: There is no procedure with the name `ga.timetree.range` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.request.EmbeddedRequest.executeRequest(EmbeddedRequest.java:176)
```

I don't see a TimeTreeProcedures class as answered in the linked issue. Is this still supported in embedded/unit testing?

Also, if it is supported, I would like to use a CustomRootTimeTree. Any help or pointer to cypher that I can define the custom root tree id in the procedure call would also be very much appreciated. Thanks for any help!

Test:

```
    @Test
    public void testSingleTimeTree() {

        User user = new User("alper@alper.com", "alper", "alper");
        userRepository.save(user);
        Collection<User> found = userRepository.findByEmail("alper@alper.com");
        user = found.iterator().next();
        Workout workout = new Workout(new DateTime().plusMonths(2).getMillis());
        workoutRepository.save(workout);
        GraphUnit.printGraph(graphDb);
        Iterable<Workout> workouts = workoutRepository.findWorkouts();

        for(Workout workout1 : workouts) {
            log.info("workout: {}", workout1);
        }
    }
```

Repo (hard coded start/end for now):

```
    public interface WorkoutRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Workout, Long> {

        @Query("CALL ga.timetree.range({start: 1506826887000, end: 1512097287, create: false})")
        Iterable<Workout> findWorkouts();

    }
```

pom.xml:

```
  <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
      <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Kay-RELEASE</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
      <!--<neo4j-ogm.version>3.0.0</neo4j-ogm.version>-->
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
              <version>${spring-data-releasetrain.version}</version>
              <scope>import</scope>
              <type>pom</type>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver</artifactId>
          <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.5</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- added by me -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.5</version>
          <type>test-jar</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.graphaware.neo4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>graphaware-framework-embedded</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.5.51</version>
          <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.graphaware.neo4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>timetree</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.1.51.27</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>neo4j-graphdb-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>neo4j-io</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.5</version>
          <type>test-jar</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.graphaware.neo4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>tests</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.5.51</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to finally get it working by debugging into the neo4j source. The tests that test and use Procedures are in https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree, and it's using ClassPathProcedureUtils class to load classes from target/classes directory. It looks for @Procedure annotations and will process those classes and the Procedures become available. Without modifying that to load classes from jars as well as target/classes, the only way I could get it to work (albeit a hack) is to copy the target/classes output from neo4j-timetree project into my project target/classes output dir.

UPDATE: 
I was also able to get it working by just registering the procedures required directly using:

```
@Bean
public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
    GraphDatabaseService gds = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabaseBuilder().newGraphDatabase();
    try {
        ClassPathProcedureUtils.registerAllProceduresAndFunctions(procedures);
        Procedures procedures = ((GraphDatabaseFacade)gds).getDependencyResolver().resolveDependency(Procedures.class);
        procedures.registerProcedure(TimedEventsProcedure.class);
        procedures.registerProcedure(TimeTreeProcedure.class);
        procedures.registerFunction(TimedEventsProcedure.class);
        procedures.registerFunction(TimeTreeProcedure.class);
      }catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("error", ex);
      }
      return gds;
}
```